# Error Trapping Best Method

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to get a list of all trouble tickets but it says that not all codes paths return a value. Does Anybody no what I am doing wrong thanks

```
public List<TroubleTicket> GetAllTroubleTickets()
{
    try
    {

        List<TroubleTicket> tickets = new List<TroubleTicket>();


        var q = _supportDeskEntities.TroubleTickets.ToList();
        return q;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {


    }


}
```

Comment: Exceptions provide useful information about the state of your software. I would not ignore them. However, when you must return something like that, I would recommend an empty list: it can be iterated without having to bother with `null` and an empty list can always provide _information_.

Answer (score 2):

If you catch an exception the function returns no value. So change this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

To this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
  return null;
}
```

Or if you want it to return an empty list when an exception is catch then you can do this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
   return new List<TroubleTicket>(0);
}
```

If we are taking about best practice then I would say that you should log the exception and then re-throw it. Like this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //write to log
   throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Is Null really the best course of action when dealing with the entity framework ??

Comment: @Sheldon : Depends on what you are expecting in the function that is calling it. I have already update the answer. You could return an empty list like above

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a value from the catch statement (or throw another exception within it). Otherwise, the function will return `null`

You can try this:

```
public List<TroubleTicket> GetAllTroubleTickets()
{
    try
    {

        List<TroubleTicket> tickets = new List<TroubleTicket>();


        var q = _supportDeskEntities.TroubleTickets.ToList();
        return q;
    }

     catch (Exception ex)
    {
       return new List<TroubleTicket>(); // This is just in case you want to ignore any exceptions

    }


}
```

or

```
catch (Exception ex)
    {
       throw new Exception("There was an error getting tickets"); // Probably not as good of a way as you lose the exception details

    }
```

Comment: I don't agree with "Otherwise, the function will return null".  Really it should be "Otherwise, the code will not compile".

Comment: @juharr I guess I'm used to VB.net compiler defaults. Not returning a value just returns `nothing` but creates a compiler warning, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1):

You only return a value if there is no exception thrown. You must either return from inside the `catch` block, or return outside the try/catch structure.

So you can either return in two separate places:

```
public List<TroubleTicket> GetAllTroubleTickets()
{
    try
    {
        var q = _supportDeskEntities.TroubleTickets.ToList();
        return q;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // You can also return "new List<TroubleTicket>()" if null is an unacceptable return value
        return null;
    }
}
```

or keep a return value variable, and set it in two different locations, and return it in one location:

```
public List<TroubleTicket> GetAllTroubleTickets()
{
    List<TroubleTicket> tickets;
    try
    {
        tickets = _supportDeskEntities.TroubleTickets.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // You can also use "new List<TroubleTicket>()" if null is an unacceptable return value
        tickets = null;
    }
    return tickets;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning anything if an exception happens and you're not assigning the list to `List<TroubleTicket> tickets` but to a different variable. You could do:

```
public List<TroubleTicket> GetAllTroubleTickets()
{
    List<TroubleTicket> tickets = null;
    bool gotTickets = true;
    try{
        tickets = _supportDeskEntities.TroubleTickets.ToList();
    }
    catch (SpecificException ex){ 
        gotTickets = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex){ // catches all other "unexpected" exceptions
        // log and/or...
        throw;
    }
    return gotTickets ? tickets : null;
}
```

But you should not catch all kind of exceptions but only specific types that you expect. You also should log all other types of exceptions.

Comment: What's the point of initializing `tickets` to an empty list when you never use it?

Comment: @juharr: i'm returning it from the method. But you'r right, i think it's better to not initialize it if it is initialized from `_supportDeskEntities.TroubleTickets.ToList()` anyway.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that you should only catch specific exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Your catch block is not returning anything.

```
public List<TroubleTicket> GetAllTroubleTickets()
{
    List<TroubleTicket> tickets =null;
    try
    {
        tickets = new List<TroubleTicket>();
        var q = _supportDeskEntities.TroubleTickets.ToList();
        return q;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       //Log or handle your error
    }

    return tickets;
}
```

Comment: There's really no point to the `tickets` variable here.  You could just remove it and return `null` at the end of the method with the same results, while avoiding initializing an unused list.